# CentOS 7 - boot order needs to be changed in order for sge to start automatically

Tags: linux, centos7, lustre

It seems like sge tries start before lustre is mounted when the server boots, which brings an error to start automatically when it reboots.
Can somebody tell me how to change the order when it boots, so sge starts after lustre is mounted?

Error message from the log:

```
Aug 12 11:46:21 dragen1 systemd: Configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/system/sge_execd.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Aug 12 11:46:40 dragen1 sge_execd: error: SGE_ROOT directory "/cm/shared/apps/sge/2011.11p1" doesn't exist
Aug 12 11:46:40 dragen1 systemd: sge_execd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 12 11:46:40 dragen1 systemd: Unit sge_execd.service entered failed state.
Aug 12 11:46:40 dragen1 systemd: sge_execd.service failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added in the following under [Unit] from the sge service

```
RequiresMountsFor=(Mount Point)
```

This fixed the problem.